# Laravel MethodNotAllowedHttpException No message - trying to Incert into mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.7

I'm very new to Laravel, im currently using version 5.7. and as im trying to put some form data into mysql table, im getting this error.

Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException
No message

However I have no idea what i'm going wrong. please help me if you can. Please see my code below.

My Routes:

```
Route::get('/invo_admin/create_new_offer', 'CreatenewofferController@index')->name('create_new_offer');
```

Also I have a sub folder called admin where i have my views for the dashboard.

```
Route::resource('admin', 'CreatenewofferController');
```

My Model:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Offers extends Model
{
protected $fillable =[
    'offer_name', 
    'offer_image', 
    'offer_discription', 
    'offer_vendor', 
    'offer_reward_amount', 
    'offer_limit', 
    'offer_duration',
    'offer_status'
];
}
```

My Controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Offers;

class CreatenewofferController extends Controller
{
 /**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function index()
{
    $title = 'this is a title';
    return view('admin.create_new_offer')->with('title',$title);
}

/**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function create()
{
    return view('admin.create_new_offer');
}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request,[
        'offer_name' => 'required', 
        'offer_image' => 'required', 
        'offer_discription' => 'required', 
        'offer_vendor' => 'required', 
        'offer_reward_amount' => 'required', 
        'offer_limit' => 'required', 
        'offer_duration' => 'required',
        'offer_status' => 'required'
    ]);
    $offers = new Offers([
        'offer_name' => $request->get('offer_name'), 
        'offer_image' => $request->get('offer_image'), 
        'offer_discription' => $request->get('offer_discription'), 
        'offer_vendor' => $request->get('offer_vendor'), 
        'offer_reward_amount' => $request->get('offer_reward_amount'), 
        'offer_limit' => $request->get('offer_limit'), 
        'offer_duration' => $request->get('offer_duration'),
        'offer_status' => $request->get('offer_status')
    ]);
    $offers->save();
    return redirect()->route('admin.create_new_offer')->with('success', 'You have successfully added a new offer');
} 
}
```

My View:

```
<form role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('invo_admin/create_new_offer') }}">
            {{csrf_field()}}
        <!-- text input -->
        <div class="form-group">
            @if(count($errors) > 0)
                <ul>
                @foreach ($errors ->all as $error)
                    <li class="text-danger">{{error}}</li>
                @endforeach
                </ul>
            @endif
            @if(\Session::has('success'))
                <p>{{\Session::get('success')}}</p>
            @endif
            <label>Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="offer_name" placeholder="Offer Name">
        </div> 
</form>
```

Comment: Looks like you're using `Route::get` to handle a post request. You need to create a post route that corresponds to your `store` controller method.

Comment: i tried that and it dose not work, do you mind giving a code example so i can make sure im doing this correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your routes.

```
Route::post('/invo_admin/create_new_offer', 'CreatenewofferController@store')->name('create_new_offer');
```

It accepts post requests and pass it on to "store" method in controller.

Comment: This has stopped the error, however still nothing being added to the database.

Comment: Yes. Your comment below is good. My point was to have route defined to accept post requests.

Answer (score 0):

So I got this taken care of.

my routes where all messed up; for example, Never use GET or POST routes, always use Recourse routes

NOT GOOD

```
Route::get('admin/vendors', 'VendorController@index')->name('whatever_name');

Route::post('admin/vendors','VendorController@index')->name('whatever_name');
```

VERY GOOD:

```
Route::resource('admin/vendors', 'VendorController', ['as'=>'admin']);
```

the last part of the correct route...

```
['as'=>'admin']
```

Is called a prefix and is used when wanting to differentiate between two section of your application, for example imagine if you had a

```
front facing website
```

and an

```
admin panel
```

In the same Laravel application, but for whatever reason the front end and back-end had the same controller named categories, this will solve that issue... anyhow, here is what you would put into a form action

```
"admin.vendors.store"
```

The **'admin"** is the prefix, and the **"vendor"** is the route, and lastly the **"store"** in the function that is located in your controller. it looks like this.

```
public function create()
{
    //
}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{
    //
}
```

I hope this helps.